# apt update && apt upgrade gives lock error on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have typed the following command:

```
$ apt update && apt upgrade
```

I am getting the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a normal user you don't have privileges to run these commands successfully, you need root privileges. To do that, you need to prepend the `sudo`-command to your commands:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

You will be prompted to enter your password then.